# Are elements of a ring actual functions or sections on the spectrum?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

An element of the coordinate ring of a variety $k[X]/I$ may be viewed as a function mapping points of the variety $V=V(I)$ to $k$.

Similarly, an element of a ring $a\in R$ may be viewed as a function on $\operatorname{Spec} R$, which maps each $\mathfrak{p}\in\operatorname{Spec}R$ to the residue of $a$ in the fraction field $R_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p}R_{\mathfrak{p}}$.

In the latter case, $a$ isn't actually a function in the strict sense, because its codomain varies from point to point. For example, $x\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ is takes a value in $\mathbb{R}$ at the prime ideal $(x),$ but a value in $\mathbb{C}$ at $(x^2+1)$.

Is there some standard construction that corrects this defect? Do the residue fields all include into a larger field which can be viewed as the single codomain for the function $a$? Or can we assemble the residue fields into a bundle over $\operatorname{Spec}R$ of which $a$ is a section?

Comment: Yes, there is a sheaf over the spectrum of which $a$ is a section; it's called the structure sheaf.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan right of course. Where's my head. Thanks.

Comment: So an element of a ring $a\in R$ is a function from $\operatorname{Spec}R$ to the étalé space of the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}R}$ on $\operatorname{Spec}R$ which localizes at ring elements, so  $\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}R}(D(a)) = R_a$